# Existence of both right and left eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I started learning about Markov Chains recently and I've seen that for a transition matrix 1 is an eigenvalue and it has a right eigenvector and a left eigenvector for this value.

Is it always so that every eigenvalue has right and left eigenvectors? If not then is there any rule as to when this happens? Also is there any intuition behind what dictates this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues, since they have the same characteristic polynomial.  So, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then there are vectors $X$ and $Y$ such that $AX=\lambda X$ and $A^TY=\lambda Y$.  Taking transposes in the last equation, $Y^TA=\lambda Y^T$, so that $A$ has both right and left eigenvectors associated with $\lambda$.